# ModelState.IsValid remains false for DropDownList, even though values to properties are binded and passed to the HttpPost method

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor

I am not sure why the ModelState validity checks keep returning false, hence preventing a write to DB action, even though values supplied to all the properties are of right DataType and successfully passed to the HttpPost method. Here is my code below:

```
**My Models**

   /*  public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string ProductDescription { get; set; }

        public int CategoryID { get; set; }

        public Category Category { get; set; }
    }
    
     public class Category
    {
        [Key]
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    } */
    

**My ViewModel**

/*  public class ProductViewModel_02
    {
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string ProductDescription { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "..")]
        public int? CategoryID { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoryList { get; set; }
    }
*/

**My Controller**

/*
 [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            var model = new ProductViewModel_02()
            {
                CategoryList = GetCategoriesListItems()
            };
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(ProductViewModel_02 pvm)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            pvm.CategoryList = GetCategoriesListItems();
            return View(pvm);
        }



        private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetCategoriesListItems()
        {
            return db.Categories.Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.CategoryID.ToString(),
                Text = x.CategoryName
            });

        }
*/

**my View Page**

/*
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CategoryID, new SelectList(Model.CategoryList, "Value", "Text"),
        "Select", new{})#
*/
```

ModalState is always invalid when form is submitted, below is the result of my debugging. The List object is null and Invalid, amongst the rest of the properties.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcG48.jpg)

Comment: Can you show the  SelectListItem class?

Comment: @FitriHalim The content of the SelectListItem Class is way more than i can post here, if you could suggest how i can post it or send directly to you. Thanks

Comment: I believe the issue is definitely in the SelectItemList class. Do SelectItemList class contain any reference to the other class that contain some kind of constraints? That might be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why the ModelState validity checks keep returning false

I test your code , find you bind values to properties(eg `CategoryID`) successfully, but you don't give the value to the `CategoryList` from view to controller. The CategoryList's value is null, so the ModelState validity checks keep returning false.

Below is a way to solve the problem, hope it can help you, try to remove below line  from your `YourProjectName.csproj` file

```
 <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#build-the-app) to know more.

Comment: Thanking you for your help, your suggestion has helped resolved the issue, i hope the edit made in file won't further create another issue, going forward.